# Global variable in imported Python Class

Tags: python-3.x, class, global-variables

It my first try to realize a "little bit bigger" project in python. Thus I want to structure the whole project using different python files. I also need some global variables. The following example works, if I put everything in one file. As soon as I split in two files it doesn't work anymore. What's an elegant way to solve the problem:

```
class MyClass:
    def call(self):
        print("In Methode call")
        self.check()

    def check(self):
        global a
        if a:
            print("a ist True")
            a = False
        else:
            print("a ist False")
            a = True

    def methode3(self):
        print("In methode 3")


if __name__=="__main__":
    a=True    
    instanz = MyClass()
    instanz.methode3()
    instanz.call()
    instanz.check()
```

This script itself works fine.

If I call it now from the following second script, I get the error that 'a'is not defined. Call of instanz.methode3() works of course.

```
import test

a = True;
instanz = test.MyClass();
instanz.methode3()
instanz.call()
```

Comment: `global` is not a convenient way to share data between methods and global scope. If you want to pass some fields to your class objects use constructors.

Answer (score 0):

The following check,

```
if __name__=="__main__":
```

Is only called from when the file is run by itself as opposed to being imported. Declaring the `a` outside this `if` should work as intended.

Also, to access the new variable `a`, use `test.a`.